# C free() on linux reports invalid next size error, array pointers, same code pass on mac

Tags: c, linux, macos, pointers

I have the following C program which malloc a two dimention array, and during the free section it reports

*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x0000000000e05070 ***

with the backtrace.

I tried the same code on a linux server and got the same error. However, same code works perfectly on my friend's mac.

I'm wondering whether this is an OS specific issue (e.g. differences in compiler)?
Or I did something in an inappropriate way but is ignored by mac OS?

```
# include <stdlib.h>

# define N 10 

int main(){
  int size = N+1;

  //memory allocation
  float **m = malloc((size)*sizeof(float*));
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<size; i++)
    m[i] = malloc((size)*sizeof(float));

  // ... do some work

  //free
  for (i=0; i<size; i++){
    printf("free: %d", i);
    free(m[i]);
    printf(" freed.\n");
  }

  free(m);
  printf("m freed.\n");

  return 0;
  }
```

PS: during the free for loop, if use

```
 for (i=size; i>=0; i--){...}
```

rather than the incremental version, it actually frees the m[i] down to 2 before the same error pop out.
Nothing went wrong for mac.

Comment: Change `int size` to `const int size`?

Comment: What are you doing in the `// do some work` section? Chances are you are overflowing the array somehow which corrupts the buffer causing the error. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680334/what-is-a-glibc-free-malloc-realloc-invalid-next-size-invalid-pointer-error-and?rq=1

Comment: Yeah, you've omitted every single part of your code which could be causing the problem, what gives?

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing out. There does exist problems in the omitted section. It is a bit large to fit everything in a question page here. I would figure out what make the differences between by specific questions in the future if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a segmentation violation because when your program tries to `free()` all the memory that's been allocated on the heap, glibc discovers that the memory has been hopelessly corrupted.

And the only part in your example where corruption can occur is the part that you neglected to include in your example.

Therefore, the answer is that the bug is the "// ... Do some work". If you remove all that code, your example will run without crashing.