# free(): invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, segmentation-fault, free

I have been developing a long running application in C++. And I have encountered segmentation fault describing

```
free(): invalid next size (normal)
```

I think it is trying to access a memory which is not accessible,but I could not identify where it is happening.I would appreciate if someone could give me knowledge or reference about the topic.

Comment: You got heap corruption

Comment: Never too late to start using valgrind.

Comment: How could I identify where this corruption is done in code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a glibc free/malloc/realloc invalid next size/invalid pointer error and how to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680334/what-is-a-glibc-free-malloc-realloc-invalid-next-size-invalid-pointer-error-and)

Comment: Are you using `free` directly in your code?

Comment: You should never use `free` in C++11 to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

When this error cropped up for me, I noticed that I had written past the limits of an array, but not so badly as to have caused it segment fault. E.g:
If your array is 10 integers in size:
int a[10],

writing to a[12] might well cause this incomprehensibly named error.