# Vector insert causes 'malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)'

Tags: c++, vector, insert, malloc, memory-corruption

I'm programming on my Raspberry Pi 3B+, with a Raspbian OS installed.

I'm having trouble with this line of code:

`clusterPoints.insert(clusterPoints.begin(), cloudPtPointer);`

Where clusterPoints is a vector of the type cloudPoint pointer, that I created, and cloudPtPointer is the pointer to the cloudPoint that I want to insert. This is my cloudPoint struct:

```
struct cloudPoint {
    double realHeight;
    cv::Point3f point;
    cloudPoint* nextPoint;
} ;
```

This code has been working for at least 2 weeks. Then I changed some stuff on another part of the project, and it started giving me this error

> "malloc(): invalid next size (unsorted)"

This error doesn't occur in the first 8 times that line of code is executed. I checked my variables, memory address and vector, and everything is working as intended, but I can't figure out what's causing a memory corruption.

---

EDIT:
I cannot paste my code, but this are the lines of code that use/have influence on the vector. Sorry in advance for this, but its the only way I can provide you more information. The code has a while (loop 4#) inside a for(loop #3) inside a for(loop #2) inside a for (loop # 1). Loop #2 and #3 are used to go through a 2d map, and Loop 4# is used to add all connected points to a vector:

```
std::vector<cloudPoint*> clusterPoints;  --> In the beggining of the function
clusterPoints.clear();                   --> In the beggining of Loop #1
clusterPoints.insert(clusterPoints.begin(), cloudPtPointer); --> At Loop 3#
clusterPoints.insert(clusterPoints.begin(), connectedPointsSet.begin(), connectedPointsSet.end()); ---> after Loop #4 (inside loop #3).
```

That connectedPointsSet, is a vector of cloudPoints. To construct that vector I  push back a set of points that are pointing to the next point, until there's nothing pointing to.

---

EDIT 2:

The change that caused the error was in 2 functions. I had to change its headers so the date type would be compatible. This are the old headers:

```
std::vector<Segmentation::cloudPoint>build2DTo3D(cv::Mat&);
bool transform2GlobalRef(std::vector<cv::Point3f>&);
```

And This are the new ones:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3f> build2DTo3D(cv::Mat&);
std::vector<Segmentation::cloudPoint> transform2GlobalRef(std::vector<cv::Point3f>&)
```

Comment: You have some Undefined Behavior in your code. Maybe you are corrupting the heap with an out of bounds write

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a glibc free/malloc/realloc invalid next size/invalid pointer error and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680334/what-is-a-glibc-free-malloc-realloc-invalid-next-size-invalid-pointer-error-and)

Comment: @drescherjm I'm using the vector class insert. So how can I be corrupting memory? The inserted value is of the vector type, its values are in the expected range, the memory address to where I'm writing is correct.

Comment: ***So how can I be corrupting memory?*** Writing to an invalid index like vec.size() or -1

Comment: @SimonKraemer No, before asking I already looked at that question, but it doesn't help.

Comment: The corruption can occur at any part of the code it need not be where the crash happened.

Comment: @drescherjm But I'm using vector::begin() to specify the memory address.

Comment: @drescherjm The vector is created and used only in that part of the code. I create the vector, and then start filling it with values...

Comment: @drescherjm Also, the vector is created inside the function that updates it, and it inserts 8 cloudPoints pointers before giving error. So, if I'm declaring the vector in the beggining of the function, using the class' insert method, inserting at a vector's position (vector::begin()), the inserted value has expected values... I cannot understand how am I corrupting memory in another part of the code

Comment: Can you add that function to your question

Comment: @drescherjm Sorry, but that's not possible. If I can add more information to help with this I will, but unfortunately I can't paste the code...

Comment: You probably will have to spend more time with your debugger. I doubt we can help.

Comment: Also if you used a source control while you developed your code you may want to bisect the problem to determine what commit you added caused the bug. [https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/beginners-guide-git-bisect-process-elimination](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/beginners-guide-git-bisect-process-elimination)

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks for the reply. Yes I understand that without the code it will be very difficult for you to help... I'll try to create a mix between psedocode and c++, so you have a better idea of what kind of process working on.

Comment: Are you looping using iterators?

Comment: In Loop #1 yes.... In the 2# and 3# I iterate over xPosition and yPosition. In loop 4 I do something like:  
   While(point.next!=Null){
       connectedPointsSet.push_back(point);
       point=point.next;
   }. 
This last loop, looks like its going to perform some Undefined Behaviour when checking for point.next, without knowing if there's any point to look at, but In my code there are the necessary conditions to solve this.

Comment: I was worried about possible iterator invalidation caused by clearing and adding items to the vectors

Comment: @drescherjm The vector I'm cleaning is different from the one i'm iterating